# What is /usr/lib/tracker?

Tags: process, ps

I ran `ps -aux` and I see like 4 of these

```
name      1696  0.0  0.3 337052 11892 tty2     SNl+ 06:46   0:00 /usr/lib/tracker
name      1698  0.3  0.4 502776 19272 tty2     SNl+ 06:46   0:24 /usr/lib/tracker
name      1704  0.0  0.3 302752 12000 tty2     SNl+ 06:46   0:00 /usr/lib/tracker
name      1705  0.0  1.5 1326320 61316 tty2    SNl+ 06:46   0:02 /usr/lib/tracker
```

Anyone got any information on what this is?
I searched the path on google and found 0 matching results. I also searched here with the same results.

Comment: That's odd, my system doesn't even have that directory. What happens when you run /usr/lib/track in a terminal?

Comment: It turns out that my terminal was to too small to display the full text.
/usr/lib/tracker/ is the full name. My apologies

Answer (score 3):

Found it on the DuckDuckGo search engine. Tracker is a search engine, search tool, and metadata storage system. It provides an indexer, tag database, extensible metadata database, and a database for first class objects.

For more info, read the Ubuntu Wiki page here: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Tracker

Or you can check out the Gnome project page here: https://wiki.gnome.org/Projects/Tracker

Answer (score 1):

I don't have this folder on my system, it could be something you installed.

`apt search tracker` tell us `tracker` is

```
metadata database, indexer and search tool
```

[Ubuntu wiki](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MetaTracker) discribes tracker in simple terms

> In layman's terms, MetaTracker (commonly referred to as Tracker) is a
>   desktop search application which allows you to quickly search your
>
> documents, photos, music, and other files. The advantage of Tracker
>   over the default search feature in Ubuntu (Nautilus -> Search for
>   files...) is that results are returned much more quickly and all of
>   the metadata (such as title, artist, track, album, composer, date,
>   etc.) of the file is included in the search. Tracker also very small
>   and efficient, consuming only abou 6 MB of RAM when indexing, and ~3
>   MB when idle.

Answer (score 0):

Tracker is a Gnome thing:  https://wiki.gnome.org/Projects/Tracker

> Tracker is a search engine, search tool and metadata storage system.
>
> It allows you to find the proverbial needle in your computer's haystack as well as providing a one stop solution to the organisation, storage and categorisation of your data.